# With PostgreSQL, how would I get the value of column one with an item in an array?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have an “Inventory" table, with two columns: id (bigint, primary key) and cards (an array).

Suppose my cards column is: `ARRAY['IZMI', 'IZCH', 'IZHI']`

How would I get the id with just one item in the array, for example `'IZMI'`?

What would my query be?

Comment: It's unclear to me if the result should only contain the value `IZMI` (i.e. the first array element) or if you are looking for rows where the array _contains_ that value.

Comment: I want to get the `id` where the array contains`IZMI` (hope this made it easier to understand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options:

One is to use the `ANY` operator:

```
select *
from inventory
where 'IZMI' = any(cards);
```

Another is the contains operator `@>`

```
select *
from inventory
where cards @> array['IZMI'];
```

The second option is useful if you need to search for multiple matches (all of them must be included in `cards`. So that would be an `AND` type comparison.

And finally the overlaps operator `&&`

```
select *
from inventory
where cards && array['IZMI'];
```

In contrast to the contains operator the overlaps operator is true if at least one element matches. So this is useful if you are want an `OR` type comparison.

More details can be found [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)